# How to make LinkedList accessible from another class to main?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

How can I access the linked list to a different class that has the main method?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Project {
    public Project {
        // Linked list declaration: 
        LinkedList<Character>list = new LinkedList<Character>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a getter in the Project class so that you can access it. Please make the question more clear also

Answer (score 2):

Declare it in the original class (e.g. Project.java) as:

```
public static LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<Character>();
```

Call it from another class as:

```
LinkedList<Character> ll = Project.list;
```

If data hiding is of essence to you, then you need to set up getters/setters for it.